# JS использовать toggle при клике на кнопку без id

Tags: javascript

пожалуйста подскажите, есть вот такие блоки:

```
<div class='block'>
    <button class='button'>Кнопка</button>
    <div class='info'></div>
</div>
<div class='block'>
    <button class='button'>Кнопка</button>
    <div class='info'></div>
</div>
<div class='block'>
    <button class='button'>Кнопка</button>
    <div class='info'></div>
</div>
```

и есть вот такой код JS

```
const button = document.getElementById('button');
const info = document.getElementById('info');

button.onclick = function(){
    info.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

Сейчас работает с помощью id . при клике на кнопку добавляется класс active и блок info показывается.

Как сделать чтобы работало без id? Чтобы по клику на кнопку ,к ближайшему к нему блоку info добавлялся класс active через toggle, а остальные блоки при этом не реагировали.

Понимаю что это как то работает this, но как не понимаю

на чистом js хочу понять как это работает

Answer (score 1):

Выбирай:

- ```
  this.classList.toggle('active');
  ```
- ```
  event.target.classList.toggle('active');
  ```
- ```
  event.currentTarget.classList.toggle('active');
  ```

Хм.. Перечитал вопрос - там не на кнопку надо, а на блок, так что так:

```
event.target.closest('.block').querySelector('.info').classList.toggle('active')
```

Только полифилл для `closest` надо подключить (в зависимости от браузеров).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, извини не совсем понимаю что имеешь ввиду под словом не на кнопку а на блок?
Не мог бы расписать как это работает по шагам?

Comment: @BigD, класс на div же.

Comment: при клике на блок будет меняться класс верно? а именно на кнопку можно как то реализовать?

Comment: @BigD, нет, неверно.

Comment: опиши пожалуйста чуть более развернуто?